# How to convert 1H candlesticks to 4H candlesticks with pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

i have a list with timestamp,low,high,open,close values of 1H candlesticks, then i calculate emas, but now i want to convert that data in a 4H candlesticks list? Heres my code so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from talib.abstract import *
    ....
    candles=[]
    for i in range(1,len(myresult)):
        candles.append({
                        'ts': myresult[i][1],
                        'low': myresult[i][2],
                        'high': myresult[i][3],
                        'open': myresult[i][4],
                        'close': myresult[i][5]
                    })
    inputs = pd.DataFrame(candles)
    a= EMA(inputs, timeperiod=50, price='close')
    b= EMA(inputs, timeperiod=100, price='close')


 ###convert candles[] or inputs to 4H ????? #######
```